# How do I force detection of an unrecognized keyboard while booted in the Live CD?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-netbook, ideapad

I am trying ubuntu netbook 10.10 on a Lenovo Ideapad s10-3c. In live mode it has not detected the entire keyboard. no num keys on...  How to make the keypad working in live mode?

Will it remain undetected if i make ubuntu permanent on my laptop? Please help me. Any type of guidelines, links, code work with detailed instructios is welcome.

(I have written above matter with onboard - typing utility).

Comment: +1 for writing up a question with an onscreen keyboard! (Not a full answer but you might want to try 11.04 instead, newer releases tend to have better hardware support)

Answer (score 1):

I hate answers like this, but unfortunately you've stumbled upon a known, and reported bug.

Your built-in keyboard will not work on Ubuntu 11.04, but if you plug-in an external one it will.

My only consolation is to say keep an eye on this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633

Hopefully, now the bug is confirmed, people will start doing their best to fix it for 11.11.

Here's to hoping!